# Why does File.ReadAllBytes work on the IIS Server when System.IO.FileStream causes an Access Violation error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST service that returns a pdf. When I use a FileStream I receive the pdf when debugging in Visual Studio but I get an Access Denied when I deploy this to IIS 7

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Document/Pdf/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DocumentPdfGet(int id)
{
        string pdfPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.pdf");
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Open);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(pdfPath);

        HttpResponseMessage innerResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        innerResult.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=" + filename + ".pdf", out contentDisposition))
        {
            innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }
        return innerResult;
    }
}
```

The error I get is :

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Sites\MySite\test.pdf' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at Workflow.Web.Controllers.WebApi.DocumentUIController.<DocumentPdfGet>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\agent\_work\10\s\....\Controllers\WebApi\MyControllerController.cs:line 220
```

But when I change the FileStream to File.ReadAllBytes I don’t get an Access denied on the server, see code below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Document/Pdf/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DocumentPdfGet(int id)
{
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;

        Byte[] pdfFile;
        string pdfPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test.pdf");
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(pdfPath);
        HttpResponseMessage innerResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
        ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(pdfFile);

        innerResult.Content = byteArrayContent;
        innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentLength = pdfFile.Length;
        innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=" + filename + ".pdf", out contentDisposition))
        {
            innerResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }
        return innerResult;
}
```

Why does File.ReadAllBytes work on the IIS Server when System.IO.FileStream causes an Access Violation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FileStream uses `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, so when your application does not have a write permission (which might be this case), then it throws an error.

On the other hand, File.ReadAllBytes uses only `FileAccess.Read`, so your application need to have only read permission.

So how to fix your code? Use the FileStream constructor that takes FileAccess argument and set it on `FileAccess.Read`.

Comment: This totally worked System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);